# 'Remote' should be top level

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently the "remote" toggle is two concepts down:

[image]

I think it should be like this:

[image]

It's not a "perk" and has nothing to do with perks or benefits.

And it's far too fundamental a feature to be on any of the secondary or tertiary levels.

Comment: *PS just BTW you've accidentally got a "cog" for the "filter" icon*

Comment: On what grounds should it be the default?

Comment: Hey Martin, good point, it's too much for Meta to mention two issues at once.  So, "Remote" choice badly needs to be moved up to the top.  It's not a "perk".

Answer (score 8):

It kind of already is... you can just write remote on the location or start writing it (and click on the first suggestion)

[image: Remote suggestion]

I do agree that we could add it somehow to make it more prominent.

Comment: That's not good UX. Only those who already know how to do this, will do it. Otherwise you can only discover this by accident.

Comment: I totally get your point... for those that don't discover it, we do have the Gear -> Perks -> Remote route... that's also weird (as a remote developer, it's not a perk to me... it's one of the most important features for me to even consider a listing)